# Disable notification after user logout in Android

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android App similar to Line/Whats app i.e. basically instant messenger. The problem I face is that even after the user logs out, The notifications are still displayed.

In other words, there is no way to disable the notifications once the user log outs. Instead, the notification are never disabled and keep on reoccurring even after log out making the app highly unusable.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that the notifications are being displayed via a Service that receives the messages in the background. What I suggest is the following:

a) This should be the simplest, since the user is logging out, there is no more need to have the background service in the background, so you can make a call to `stopSelf()` when the trigger to log out is made. If the logout action is happening on an activity, you can notifiy the service via either a broadcast, or via a message, depending on how you've established your service.

b)If you want to try something else, you can add a flag to your service class: `isUserLoggedOut` and set it to true when you do the logout workflow. Then, you can check for this flag when deciding whether of not to notify the user.

```
private void showNotification () {
    if (isUserLoggedOut)
       return;
    //shownotification otherwise
}
```

c) In all honesty though, I strongly advice to revise your logout workflow, to clear existing persistent data from that user (access tokens, etc), close the main activity for chats and display the logon activity again, and disable any processing of messages in the service, as your service shouldn't be handling messages for any account, assuming the user signed out.

Answer (score 0):

Cancel all your notifications using the NotificationManager once the user logs out of your app.